# Async ConfigureAwait(false) Exception Handling-Long Running Processes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, configureawait

I have two long processes that are inside a Task.Run block that I want to run concurrently and capture any exceptions that may occur. I don't want to wait for these tasks to complete and I want to avoid deadlocks so I added ConfigureAwait(false). My first question is how do I execute both methods without waiting and handle the exception for either one? Currently my code looks like this:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                EmailTicket();
                PostETicket();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If I place await before EmailTicket() and PostETicket() then only method catches the exception and the process ends. If I don't await for the process like above, will I run into any issues?

Comment: There's no point in configuring an await if you never actually await.  You're configuring something you're not doing, so it's not accomplishing anything.  There's also no point in making a lambda async if you're not going to await anything.

Comment: @Servy so as long as I don't await, I won't run into any deadlocks?

Comment: There are lots of ways of writing code that deadlocks without using `await`.  All I said is configuring await is pointless if you're not awaiting the returned value.

Comment: Do you want the `PostETicket` to run after the completion of `EmailTicket`, or both of them to run concurrently?

Comment: Both to run concurrently without waiting